# new Java class in Scala: takes type paremeters

Tags: java, scala, generics

There is a Class:

```
public class DeserializerHelper<T> extends AbstractSchemaHelper {
    public DeserializerHelper(Map<String, Object> config, Class<T> messageClass) {
        this(config, messageClass, null);
    }
}
```

I am trying to new it in Scala:

```
val decoder = new DeserializerHelper(config, classOf[GenericRecord])
```

But I got `Type DeserializerHelper takes type parameters`.

```
[ERROR]  found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Object]
[ERROR]  required: java.util.Map[String,Object]
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you tried to feed it the wrong kind of `Map`. Scala's `scala.collection.immutable.Map` and Java's `java.util.Map` are unrelated. This here works just fine:

Java:

```
public class DeserializerHelper<T> {
  public DeserializerHelper(java.util.Map<String, Object> conf, Class<T> msg){}
}
```

Scala:

```
object newDeserializerHelper {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val config = new java.util.HashMap[String, AnyRef]
    val decoder = new DeserializerHelper(config, classOf[String])
    println("compiles...")
  }
}
```

If you compile the former with `javac` and the latter with `scalac`, then everything works without errors or warnings.

Alternatively, use `JavaConverters` on Scala's side.